# How to prove that a function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Could you give me some hint how to solve this question:

Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function for all $0<x<1$,$f(0)=1,f'(x)>0$ in the given interval.
It is obvious that $f$ is continuous for all $0<x<1$, but is it continuous at $x=0$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,f(0)=1. I edited my post.

Comment: No, of course; consider $f(x)=x$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: I only intended to mention that f'(x) exists for all 0<x<1,sorry about confusion, as you may see , English is not my native language.

Comment: The answer by @egreg continues to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and the example is very simple:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x=0$}\\
x & \text{if $0<x<1$}
\end{cases}
$$
The function is differentiable in the open interval $(0,1)$ and its derivative is $f'(x)=1>0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. However,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0\ne1=f(0)
$$
so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Differentiability at every point of $(0,1)$ can't imply anything about the behavior of the function at $0$, because for each $x>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset(0,1)$ and the differentiability of $f$ at $x$ only involves the values of $f$ in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, which $0$ doesn't belong to.

Answer (score -1):

First, knowing the definition of a continuous function helps.

Quoting wikipedia here,

A function f(x) is continuous at point c if the limit of f(x) as x approaches c is f(c).

You have some facts stated earlier:

1. f(x) is differentiable in 0 < x < 1
2. f(0) = 1
3. f'(x)>0 in (0,1)

We should check the limit of f(x) as x approaches 0. The answer is going to be a number, whose derivative is >0. However, Since f'(0) = 0, we can automatically assume that

lim as f(x) approaches 0 isn't equal to f(0) because their derivatives are different.

Hence f(x) is not continuous at 0.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: No, f(x) is not differentable at 0.

Comment: true, thanks ill edit

Comment: You're still using $f'(0)$ in a number of places. Additionally, reasoning that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) \neq f(0)$ just because "their [(whose?)] derivatives are different" doesn't seem correct.